# How can I use npm package selenium-standalone with Nightmare.js instead of downloading the selenium jar?

Tags: javascript, selenium, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

As the title suggests, I want to use Nightmare.js with selenium. However, their documentation only mentions the `selenium-standalone-xxxx.jar`.

I know that there is an npm package called `selenium-standalone`. We can't I use that with Nightmare? And if I can, how? Nightmare's configuration needs a path for Selenium jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the selenium-server-standalone-jar packages

```
npm install --save-dev selenium-server-standalone-jar
```

more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-server-standalone-jar